# Favicon at root of the site but not displaying

Tags: html, root, favicon, head, ico

I recently put my portfolio online and I can't figure out why the favicon is not showing.

I created a file called **favicon.ico** that is at the root of the website (see here: www.paulinelephew.com/favicon.ico)

Here is the code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.paulinelephew.com/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.paulinelephew.com/favicon.ico"  />
```

For some reason it won't display, help really appreciated here!

Thank you!

Pauline

Comment: i can't see your code

Comment: it displays for me when i visited in chrome

Comment: Your icon is fine. Browsers cache favicons and that's probably why you don't see it yet.

Comment: Interesting! So apparently it works in Chrom but not Safari or Firefox :/

Comment: So when I delete the cache and restart firefox it'll all work ? :)

Comment: Empty browser cache, and retry your test

Answer (score 3):

Same "problem".
Ctrl + F5 makes a "hard refresh" and the icon is shown.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30990460/5322744

Answer (score 1):

Remove all <link> tags used for your favicon. Simply put your favicon.ico file to web root.

Secondly, your file: http://www.paulinelephew.com/favicon.ico is a PNG image. Please convert it to ico format.

It will just work.

Comment: The <link> comment could use some clarification. Having your favicon.ico in the root directory will work without needing any code, yes, but <link> tags are fully supported just the same. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use

Comment: @david-metcalfe: Yes you are right, there is no issue of supporting 'link' tag. But there was reported error that the favicon.ico wasn't ICO but PNG.